# undoing git merge after merge.renameLimit warning plus conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I am trying to do a merge squash from a devel branch into the master.

```
stefanos-imac:trunk borini$ git merge --squash devel
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in test1
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your merge.renamelimit variable to at least 2224 and retry the command.
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

fair enough.

```
stefanos-imac:trunk borini$ git config merge.renameLimit 999999
```

Then I try to undo the merge and redo it with the higher limit

```
stefanos-imac:trunk borini$ git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

Ok, so maybe I have to do as it says and just reinvoke the merge command

```
stefanos-imac:trunk borini$ git merge --squash devel
fatal: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

oh git, why are you such a git?

More to the point, does anyone know how to get out of this situation ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Em, `git reset --hard origin/master`?

Answer (score 8):

The modern way to undo a merge is (but this only works when MERGE_HEAD is present):

```
git merge --abort
```

And the slightly older way, which will work in this case (MERGE_HEAD is missing):

```
git reset --merge
```

The old-school way described in accepted answer (warning: will discard all your local changes):

```
git reset --hard
```

So notice that `git merge --abort` is only equivalent to `git reset --merge` given that `MERGE_HEAD` is present. This can be read in the git help for merge command.

```
git merge --abort is equivalent to git reset --merge when MERGE_HEAD is present.
```

After a failed merge, when there is no `MERGE_HEAD`, the failed merge can be undone with `git reset --merge` but not necessarily with `git merge --abort`.

Comment: git reset --merge, this works for me for the described MERGE_HEAD is missing.

Answer (score 4):

`git merge --abort` will also do the trick. A bit quicker than typing the full git reset command.

Abort also works with `rebase` and `cherry-pick`.

Comment: this particular case clearly indicates that merge --abort is failing, which I've seen myself.  Always sad to see abort fail :(